# Join tables when 3 column in first table that can point to same column in second table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I have the following DB structure:

[image]

And right now I can't make up a query to get
a creator data, admin data and tech data from item_contacts...

What kind of JOIN I need to use and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want 3 joins on `item_contacts` - one for each column whose `data` you want to recover:

```
select
    i.*,
    cc.data as creator_data,
    ca.data as admin_data,
    ct.data as tech_data
from items i
inner join item_contacts cc on cc.contact_id = i.creator_id
inner join item_contacts ca on ca.contact_id = i.admin_id
inner join item_contacts ct on ct.contact_id = i.tech_id
```

Comment: . . I would suggest `LEFT JOIN`.  There is no indication that the columns are `NOT NULL`.